# GPP Delete policy not working on Windows Server 2008 R2 RDS when deleting shared printee

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I have one AD Security group for each shared printer, I have one GPP that map the printer if the user is in the security group that belong to the printer. And one GPP to delete the printer if the user is NOT member of the security group. The security group is also applied in “Security” tab on the printsrv with PRINT rights and “everyone” is removed. This works 100 % on Windows 7 clients and Windows 2003 Terminal Servers. But on Windows 2008 R2 RDS this dont work.The delete Policy will not delete the shared printer. No warning in any logs, and the gpresult shows that the gpo setting applyed sucessfully. The only way I can make the Delete policy work is if i give the user print rights on the printer on the printsrv. Looks like for the policy to work on 2008 R2 the user must have print rights on the printer object on the printserver. The GPP Delete Policy will not delete printers that have status : access denied.
Beginning to wonder if this is a bug in Windows 2008 R2.
Anyone else had this problem?